# re-login with another account

Tags: feature-request, bug, login

There might be a funny bug in stackoverflow. When I want to log-out, I am always being obliged to delete my browser's history, at every turn, in order to login with another account. When I press log-out button, it is logging out. But when I press the log-in button, It is always log in my previous account which I've just logged out. Is it a bug or just my browser's fault? (I don't save passwords or cookies in my browser) Thanks...

**EDIT** : I want the logout button forwards me to the OpenID log out page to confirm. then I could really log out instead of being obliged to delete my browser's history within..

Comment: This is how OpenID works, you are still logged into your OpenID provider.

Comment: Then, log out button goes for nothing.

Comment: This request should be changed to "Remove the logout button as it doesn't do what it says on the tin."

Comment: @ChrisLively It would be unmerciless cuz I want a logout button which is really be able to log out :)

Comment: An alternate, but better request, then would be: *Change the Logout button so it forwards people to the openid logout page to confirm*.

Comment: Though this does raise the issue of why you want to log in with another account. Why do you have more than one account on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I wanted to illustrate the situation by saying another account. Another account is not mine, might be my friend's. problem?

Comment: @aphex - If you personally don't have multiple accounts then it's not a problem.

Comment: Lol, thanks for outing yourself.

Comment: Dear all, I have problems making the OpenID login work properly with my sockpuppet accounts. Therefore, I have a feature request to make logging in and out easier so that I can use my sockpuppets more easily to upvote my other posts that haven't received enough attention. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think this is a reasonable request. I like to login from other people's computers when I'm visiting, and since I participate in quite a few SE sites, I have to log out of every one of them individually or going back to the login screen will just login automatically again.

Comment: I also love how you say it "might be" your friend's account.